# Compute a limit in two variables, with factorial and tangent

Tags: calculus, limits

Exceed the limits of the length of title:

$$
\lim_{\substack{x\to+\infty\\ y\to+\infty}}
  \left(
    \frac{\sqrt[x+y]{(x!)^y\cdot(y!)^x}}
         {\tan(x-y)\tan(x+y)-\pi^{xy}}
    -\pi^{x!+y!}
  \right)
$$

I only know that there is a approximation of the factorial:

> $$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$

Comment: have you substituted that in the limit to see what happens?

Comment: @Ant but the key is that the tangent confuses me a lot.

Comment: Try setting $x=y$ (to get rid of the tangent) and then $x  = y +1$ to see if the limit exists in the first place  :)